# Simple spring boot + react componnent

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a webapp up with react, and a backend webapp with spring boot.

i'm using this on the APP.js

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        greeting: "This is a false greeting" 
      }
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/test2").then(function(response) {
               return response.text();
            }).then((text) => {
                  this.setState({greeting: text})
               });
     }
```

And this on the controller :

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
        return "This is a greeting from spring";
    }
```

It works, with

{this.state.greeting}

I can see "This is a greeting from spring "

I would like to send a value from the app.js ( a Number chosen with a button ) 
to the spring side controller, the controller would take this value, chose a random value, compare both values, and send a response.

I'm stuck at the " Send a value from the app.js to the spring side controller "

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the query params to the URL in the GET request, on your UI.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    greeting: "This is a false greeting",
    selectedNumber: 0 //update this state variable on button click
  }

} 

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/test2?selectedNumber=" + this.state.selectedNumber).then(function(response) {
           return response.text();
        }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
           });
 }
```

On your Spring-boot API controller, add the RequestParam so that the API is able to read the query params from the request.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/test2")
public String test2(@RequestParam("selectedNumber") int selectedNumber) {
    System.out.println(selectedNumber);
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    return "This is a greeting from spring";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect !